# How to convert a python script into an Android app

Tags: python, android, development-environment

I have a basic python script in a bash file that I execute from the command line (prompts to user questions). Is it possible to convert it into an Android app easily? Thanks.

Comment: Use Google Collabs with these configurations:
https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a little open-ended, thus I will provide a somewhat open-ended answer. Many tutorials can be found online that show how to create such an app in Python step-by-step. [This tutorial](https://realpython.com/mobile-app-kivy-python/) being one of them. In your case, the 'Packaging Your App for Android' section will provide information about how to convert from python to an Android application.

Comment: I had seen this page, thanks. I wanted a more quick example, like for instance, "hello" on terminal type of thing.